# Early history of men

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

I am trying to figure out the early history of men. After reading just *LotR* and its appendices I have several questions revolving around which groups are which:
Edain, Dúnedain, Númenóreans, and Elf-friends.

If I understand correctly:

1. The Edain are the first three houses of men [edit: to associate with elves]
2. Two Edain (Tuor and Beren) marry into the Elvish lines Noldor (Idril) and Sindar (Lúthien). All of the offspring of these two marriages are called Half-elven or Peredhil. At some point in time all of the living Peredhil are give the choice to become either Elf or Man.
3. After the War of the Great Jewels, which **some** Edain help the Eldar, these Edain are rewarded with their own land: Númenor.
4. Elros (a Peredhil) chooses to become man. He becomes the first king of Númenor.

*LotR*, Appendix F; 1. "Of men":

> After the overthrow of the Dark Power, in which Beleriand was for the most part drowned or broken, it was granted as a reward to the Elf-friends that they also, as the Eldar, might pass west over Sea. [...] **Most** of the Elf-friends, therefore, departed and dwelt in Númenor. [...] These were the Númenóreans, the Kings of Men, whom the elves called the Dúnedain.
>
> [...] Most of the Men of the northern regions of the West-land were descended from the Edain of the First Age, or of their close kin. [...] Of this kind were the peoples of the upper vales of Anduin: the Beornings, and the Woodmen of Western Mirkwood, [...] Men of Long Lake and of Dale. [...] the folk known in Gondor as Rohirrim.

So my questions:

1. What happened to the Edain who didn't marry into the Elvish lines? Did they not all go to Númenor? Did they eventually become the Northmen?
2. Is Elros the only half-elf to choose mortality (besides Arwen)?
3. Did **all** the half-elves who chose mortality go to Númenor? Did any non-half-elf (i.e. full human) Edain go to Númenor?
4. What about the half-elves who chose elfdom? Where do they go? I think I read that Rivendell was a haven for half-elves who chose elfdom.
5. Depending on answer to #1, are **all** Númenóreans descendants of Elros?
6. Are the Dúnedain and the Númenóreans the same group just two different names?

Sorry for asking so many questions. I just finished the book and I've written down a lot of questions.

Comment: I like the quality of research you've shown here, but usually it works better to ask several separate questions instead of one, multi-pronged question.  This ensures the answers you get properly address all your points.  You can edit this question down to a couple -tightly-related questions, then post new questions asking what you edited out of this one.

Comment: And then you can also use the same or similar lead-in for all of the separate questions. You can also link to the other questions, which helps draw attention to your many questions.  Welcome to the Sci-fi Stack Exchange, this is a great first post you've made!

Comment: ok, split off the obviously non-related questions here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34748/numenorean-interaction-with-other-men I think all of the remainging questions go together. They are about the splitting up of one tightly mixed group. I'm also willing to get partial answers =P

Comment: "The Edain are the first three houses of men." <- Are you sure this is true? I was under the impression they're just three houses that chose to associate themselves with the Elves, and that there were plenty of other men (whether in "houses" or not) at that time.

Comment: yes @einpoklum you're right. I've update my original question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What happened to the Edain who didn't marry into the elvish lines? Did
> they not all go to Númenor? Did they eventually become the Northmen?

The First Age ended with the fall of Angband and the drowning of Beleriand.  The island of Númenor was raised from the Sea by the Valar as a gift for the Edain.  Númenor was a place where the greatness of men was preserved for a while.

All members of the [First and Third Houses of the Edain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edain) who wished could move there, and a greater part did.  There is no relation between marrying an Elf and being allowed to go to Númenor.

> Is Elros the only half-elf to choose mortality (besides Arwen)?

Arwen's brothers, Elladan and Elrohir, were one fourth men.  I don't believe it is known what their choice was.  From [Letter 153](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Letter_153): "When she wed Aragorn she made "the choice of Lúthien". Elrond’s sons, Elladan and Elrohir delayed their choice, left untold in the story."

> Did all the half-elves who chose mortality go to Númenor? Did any non-half-elf (i.e. full human) Edain go to Númenor?

At the time Númenor was founded there were only two half-elves, Elros and Elrond.  Elros became the first King of Númenor.  All other Edain where fully human.

> What about the half-elves who chose elfdom? Where do they go? I think I read that Rivendell was a haven for half-elves who chose elfdom.

Elrond became Lord of Rivendell.  He was the only half-elf there.  His children (Arwen, Elladan and Elrohir) were three-quarter-elves ;)  There are too few half-elves to speak of them as a class.

> Depending on answer to #1, are all Númenóreans descendants of Elros?

As said above, I think many Númenóreans were unrelated to Elros.

> Are the Dúnedain and the Númenóreans the same group just two different names?

At the end of the Second Age, the formerly flat Earth was made into a globe.  Númenor was sunk in that cataclysm.  [A few Númenóreans escaped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elendil), and founded two Kingdoms in Exile: Arnor and Gondor.

The Númenóreans who survived the sinking of Númenor were called the Dúnedain, literally the "men of the west".  So the Númenóreans of the Second Age became the Dúnedain of the Third Age.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure why you think there were more Half-elven than just Elrond and Elros. As you say, the only two Elf-Man marriages were Tuor/Idril and Beren/Lúthien: their descendants, Elwing and Eärendil, married each other, so the elven descent was just contained in their children, Elrond and Elros. (Note that these 'half-elven' also had a component of Maiar blood, since Lúthien's mother was Melian the Maia.)

The other Númenóreans were just the rest of the descendants of the Three Houses, and were all fully men and had no elven blood. Elrond was the only half-elf at Rivendell, or indeed anywhere else. Having chosen to be a member of the Eldar, he sailed to the West at the end of *LotR*, and presumably lived there forever.

And yes, Dúnedain means "men of the West", in other words, [those descended from] the Númenóreans.

I note that you've tagged this question with "Lord of the Rings", which implies you haven't read *The Silmarillion*, where a lot of this is explained in much greater detail. *Unfinished Tales* also contains a large section on the history of Númenor itself.

**Edited after comment** Dior was father of Elwing, Eluréd and Elurín: the latter two were killed and didn't have any descendants. Arwen, Elrohir and Elladan were the children of Elrond, and made the choice when Elrond went over Sea; they all chose to be counted among Men.

And yes, only the descendants of Elros had Elvish ancestry, but as Mike points out over the course of 6,000 years that likely has grown to encompass most of the population of Gondor.

Comment: Elrond may have been the only "half-elf" (although as you mention, he was actually half human, 3/8 elf and 1/8 Maia), but Arwen, Elladan, Elrohir, and probably the entire population of Gondor (through the line of descent from Elros) had varying mixtures of human and elvish descent.

Comment: In the case of Elrond and Elros, being human or elven wasn't about blood or percentages of ancestry. It was about choice. Elrond was Half-Elven in name, but 100% Elven in essence, once he made his choice. Likewise Elros being Human.

Comment: not that this is 100% correct http://lotrproject.com/ but I'm guessing that Dior, Elurin, Elured, Elwing, Earendil, Elros, Elrond, Arwen, Elrohir, and Elladan were all half-elven. I know some of the back story about what happened to Elwin and Earendil, but what about the others? Were they given the same choice?

Comment: So, if some of the pure-human Edain became the Numenoreans, then only the descendants of Elros were elvish ancestry? All other Numenoreans were just human?

Comment: My *recollection* is that ALL the ones who removed to Numenor were rewarded with long life many times the length of normal men, so their long lifespan is not due to being elvish by birth but rather their service. However the line of Elros had longer life expectancy even so.

Comment: The children of Imrazor and Mithrellas were half-elves too, but they were mortal by default, which appears to be the standard: only Earendil and Elwing (and their children) were given a choice.  LotR says only *three* marriages of Edain and Eldar (Beren & Luthien, Tuor & Idril, Aragorn & Arwen) but Mithrellas was an Avar, not an Elda.  There may be other (unrecorded) unions involving the Avari.

Comment: @tir38 Before Eärendil and Elwing, none of them lived long enough. In fact, the "default" seem to be that if you had a mortal parent, you too were mortal. The idea of having a choice didn't arrive until Eärendil and Elwing arrived in Valinor. In short, Mandos asked if a mortal should live after setting foot in Aman. Ulmo countered that Eärendil was part Elf. Manwë decide that Eärendil and Elwing (and their children) should have the choice.

Comment: (I'm torn between Elrond's children having a choice, in which case Elrohir and Elladan are never shown to have made one; and Elrond's children simply being Elves by nature of their birth to two Elvish parents, with Arwen choosing mortality the same way Luthien did, independently of her heritage.)

Comment: @horatio Elros was given the longest span (around 500 years). His descendents were given something around 400 years, and the average Numenorean around 200 years. Both those dwindled over time; Aragorn seemed to have lived longer than anyone except in the Third Age (except perhaps for the early kings of Arnor), but still lived "only" a bit over 200 years.

Answer (score 3):

After reading *The Silmarillion*, I can answer some of my own questions.

> Are the Dúnedain and the Númenóreans the same group just two different names?

Same group two different names. Quoting *The Silmarillion*:

> Then they went up out of the sea and found a country fair and fruitful, and they were glad. And they called that land Elenna, which is Starwards; but also Anadune, which is Westernesse, Númenor in the High Eldarin tongue.
>
> This was the beginning of that people that in the Grey-elven speech are called the Dúnedain: the Númenóreans, Kings among Men.

---

> Did all the half-elves who chose mortality go to Númenor? Did any non-half-elf (i.e. full human) Edain go to Númenor?

As @Daniel and @Andomar said, Elros was the only half-elf to choose mortality and he becomes first king of Númenor. A lot (most?) of the Edain alive in Middle-earth go to Númenor. Some do stay in Middle-earth. What becomes of them isn't spoken about in *The Silmarillion*.

---

> What about the half-elves who chose elfdom? Where do they go? I think I read that Rivendell was a haven for half-elves who chose elfdom.

This is exclusively Elrond. His tale after the forming of Númenor is told somewhat in [*The Akallabêth*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akallab%C3%AAth) and "[Of the Rings of Power and the Third Age](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Of_the_Rings_of_Power_and_the_Third_Age)."

---

> Depending on answer to #1, are all Númenóreans descendants of Elros?

No.

Answer (score 0):

> Depending on answer to #1, are all Númenóreans descendants of Elros?

Maybe.  Many men emigrated to Númenor along with Elros the first king.  Many of those men did not have, children, and many had families which died out after a few generations.  But many or most of those men would have descendants lasting until the fall of Númenor, and a good fraction of those men would have descendants among the Dúnedain who colonized Arnor and Gondor.

With so many thousands of men colonizing Númenor, there would be many families  descending in the male line from father to son to grandson from those first colonists.

Thus the vast majority of Númenóreans were not descended from Elros in the male line from father to son.

However, a large proportion of the Númenóreans might have been descended from Elros if descent in both male and female lines is counted.  Many of the Númenóreans would be  descended from son to daughter to son to son to daughter to son to daughter to daughter... and so on from Elros.

In the three thousand years that Númenor lasted, ALL the Númenóreans would have been become descended from Elros if their generations had been as short as those of modern men.  Because the Númenórean generations were several times as long as normal human generation, I am not so sure that all Númenóreans were descended from Elros.

But by the time of *Lord of the Rings* everyone in Gondor should have been descended from Elros many times over, though I do not know if anyone in Gondor could actually trace his ancestry back to Elros.